# How to left join more than 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I'm struggling as a junior to create a view based on 5 tables: Country, Business, SubBusiness, Role and Type

```sql
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT DISTINCT `a`.`country`, `b`.`business`, `c`.`sub_business`, `d`.`role`, `e`.`type`

FROM ((`country` `a` LEFT JOIN `business` `b` on  ((`a`.`username`=`b`.`username`)))    
    LEFT JOIN `sub_business` `c` on ((`a`.`username`=`c`.`username`)))
    LEFT JOIN `role` `d` on ((`a`.`username`=`d`.`username`)))
    LEFT JOIN `type` `e` on ((`a`.`username`=`e`.`username`)));
```

It works for joining 3 tables, after that I receive a syntax error.
And also, because USERNAME is in all the tables is the a way to make more performant?
Thank you in advance for all the inputs !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong  (and useless) sequence of ()

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT DISTINCT `a`.`country`, `b`.`business`, `c`.`sub_business`, `d`.`role`, `e`.`type`
FROM `country` `a` 
LEFT JOIN `business` `b` on  `a`.`username`=`b`.`username`  
LEFT JOIN `sub_business` `c` on `a`.`username`=`c`.`username`
LEFT JOIN `role` `d` on `a`.`username`=`d`.`username`
LEFT JOIN `type` `e` on `a`.`username`=`e`.`username`;
```

Comment: ...which is odd, because that sort of thing is normally created automatically by the server